# Why Androidx.media3.exoplayer Video Next (exo_next) button not Clickable?

Tags: java, android, androidx, exoplayer, android-media3

I Create an app for playing video with fetching folders and files from storage.

I implement **Androidx.media3.exoplayer** and playing video from a folder that contains multiple videos.
My problem is Next Button is unClickable, all button are clickable by default but Next Button is not clickable.

**Note**: I'm not customised just play for test exoplayer and i got a problem.

If Anyone fix this issue?
Please help me...❤️❤️❤️

[This is problems image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wup6S.jpg)
[image]